# Effective Python multiple if conditions with different behavior evaluation

Tags: python

Is there a way to effectively (visually/organization not performance) code up the possible actions when you have multiple chained-if-conditions to check for?

Here's how people do it now.
Example:

```
variable = 0 # can be 0 or 1
variable1 = 'a' # can be 'a', 'b'

if variable == 0 and variable1 == 'a':
    print('1')
elif variable == 0 and variable1 == 'b':
    print('2')
elif variable == 1 and variable1 == 'c':
    print('3')
elif variable == 1 and variable1 == 'd':
    print('4')
```

Or you could do NESTED if loops.

But this obviously becomes very untenable when you have:

```
variable = True # can be True or False
variable1 = 'a' # can be 'a', 'b', 'c'
variable2 = '1a' # can be '1a', '1b', '1c'
variableNth = 'aaa' # can be 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'... where Nth is large
if variable == 1 and variable1 = 'a' and variable2 = '1a' and variableth = 'aaa':
   print('yay!')
elif variable .... (you get the picture)
```

So is there an effective way to loop through all possible outcomes and write the desired behaviors given all possibilities of combination?

My current thought is:

```
variable = 0 # can be 0 or 1
variable1 = 'a' # can be 'a', 'b'

# slightly more visually appealing? 
results_dict = {}
results_dict[str('0') +str('a')] = result1_func
results_dict[str('0') +str('b')] = result2_func
results_dict[str('1') +str('a')] = result3_func
results_dict[str('1') +str('b')] = result4_func
# and for more possibilities:
results_dict[str('0') + str('a') + str('aaa')] = result5_func

def result1_func(*arg, **karg):
    print('yay!')

def result2_func(*arg, **karg):
    print('no')
def result3_func(*arg, **karg):
    print('3')
def result3_func(*arg, **karg):
    print('4')

def func_else(*arg, **karg):
    print('5')
```

and you use it by:

```
>>>> func = results_dict[str(variable) + str(variable1)]
>>>> func(variable, variable1)
```

but now dealing with generic 'else' cases is more annoying if they aren't caught with:

```
>>>> func = results_dict.get(str(variable) + str(variable1), func_else)
```

Is this the way to go?  Are there solutions already out there? (frameworks I can inherit to do what I want to do?)

edit to clarify func_else:
    func_else can be used in the case of not writing down all possibilities:

```
variable = 0# can be 0 or 1
variable1 = 'a' # can be 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

but I only care about the combinations (0 and a) or ('1' and 'c').
then I don't need to fill out all 6 possibilities, just 2, and catch the rest in my func_else

Comment: I think a dictionary of functions would work much better than a ton of if statements, but you can do data validation rather than have this "func_else" function. What are your functions doing?

Comment: this is just a generalized question.  I was writing out lot's of if/else statements and finding it kind of ugly.  My print statements are very simple print statements.

I was thinking use: func_else for the "other cases", see edit

Comment: The reason I was asking is because the functions seem like a wrapper for `print`. You could just do `print(results_dict[X])`

Comment: yea.  but we can do more things in them.  like change object variables.  combine lists! do other API stuff.  I just simplified the example.  but there are definitely other ways to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use tuples as keys and build the dictionary directly

```
func_dict = {(0, '1') : func1, ....}
.....
result = func_dict[(variable, variable1)](<params>)
```

Comment: yea, but is this a good way of thinking about the problem?  is a dictionary of functions the good way to go?

Comment: In my book - yes. I do it rather often. It makes for cleaner code, and I believe that dictionary lookup is faster than passing through several _elifs_

Comment: @user1639926, and you may add _try..except KeyError_ to handle unknown combinations

Comment: neat.  and here I was thinking (and hoping) that this dictionary lookup was passe. and there were more efficient ways of dealing with these cases (or at least someone dealt with it in some framework I can download)

Comment: @user1639926, BTW, my solution is the same as suggested by freakish - minus wrapper class (which I think is redundant)

Comment: @user1639926, they main principle - KISS (keep it simple stupid). Dictionary is all the framework you need. _try...except_ is common way of catching unknown keys (again, more efficient and more pythonic than _if_)

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with defaults by inheriting from dict:

```
class Controller(dict):
    def __init__(self, default=None):
        self._default = default
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return super(Controller, self).__getitem__(key)
        return self._default
```

It can be used pretty much the same as the dictionary you've used, except that you have to initialize it with default function:

```
results_dict = Controller(default=fn)

func = results_dict[str(variable) + str(variable1)] # will always work
func(variable, variable1)
```

Other then that your approach is fine and I would definitely go that way.

Comment: that's pretty cool.  yea that can be used to catch that pesky "else"